# C++ vector iterator not incremental

Tags: c++, object, vector, iterator, erase

I've been having a headache with this problem. I've challenged myself to make a CLI space shooter, where you have you spaceship, lasers and meteors to shoot. The problem is this: whenever a laser or a meteor reaches the boundaries of our arena, I want to erase from the vector so that it wouldn't cluster it up. Here's how my working code looks now:

```
        std::vector<Meteoras>::iterator itMet = meteorai.begin();
        std::vector<Lazeris>::iterator itLaz = lazeriai.begin();
        while (itMet != meteorai.end() || itLaz != lazeriai.end())
        {
            if (itLaz != lazeriai.end())
            {
                if (itLaz->getCoord()->x == j && itLaz->getCoord()->y == i)
                {
                    itLaz->move(); 
                    ++j; 
                    if (itLaz->getCoord()->x >= ILGIS - 1) continue;
                    else std::cout << itLaz->getIcon();
                }
                ++itLaz;
            }
            if (itMet != meteorai.end())
            {
                if (itMet->getCoord()->x - 1 == j && itMet->getCoord()->y == i)
                {
                    itMet->move();
                    ++j;
                    if (itMet->getCoord()->x <= 0) continue;
                    else std::cout << itMet->getIcon();
                }
                ++itMet;
            }
        }
```

So there are two "continues" in there. Instead of them I tried placing iterator removals (as in `itLaz = lazeriai.erase(itLaz)` but that the program seemed to crash during runtime giving the error that I stated before. I tried doing other logical checks but that didn't seem to work either. I would appreciate if someone could explain a proper way of removing a useless object (in this case a meteor/laser) from a vector.

Comment: Erasure of vector elements makes the iterator invalid.  You will need to restart at the beginning after you erase an element of the vector.

Comment: You may be able to start at the end of the vector and proceed to the beginning of the vector.  Any erased elements affect the order of elements that you have already searched.  No guarantees that the iterator will be valid after an element has been erased, even going reverse direction.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Aha. Okay. But why no reset it to the beginning of the vector? It would start cycling through it again until it hits another deletable, wouldn't it?

Comment: The issue is that the iterator is no longer valid.  Restarting from the beginning gives you a valid iterator.  You could reload from `begin()` and then add in the offset of where you left off.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I seem to have fixed. Added 2 new bools (1 for lasers and 1 for meteors) which logically check if need to increment the iterator. It's not needed if it's recently been erased and reset to begin(). Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: That code is neither complete nor minimal; please replace it with a [mcve] of your problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The comment about `erase()` invalidating an iterator is true. The part about needing to restart at the beginning is wrong. (You could do, but you certainly don't need to.)

`erase()` returns a still-valid iterator which points to the element after the erased item.

```
if( test for erasing )
{
    itLaz = lazeriai.erase(itLaz);
}
else
{
   ++itlaz;
}
```

You might be able to refactor your code to use `std::remove_if()` instead.